# Checking to see if key-value has the same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm turning a .csv file into an array of key-value pairs, I'm trying to print each unique value and i'm trying to figure out how I can check to make sure the values aren't identical. So for example:

```
    var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv);
```

will turn everything into

```
 [
{heading1:"value1_1",heading2:"value2_1",heading3:"value3_1",heading4:"value4_1",heading5:"value5_1"}
{heading1:"value1_2",heading2:"value2_2",heading3:"value3_2",heading4:"value4_2",heading5:"value5_2" }
]
```

I want to check if heading1 has the same value in both instances and if it does to only print the first instance of that value.

Comment: post such json which have duplicate values so that it can easily be figure out

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data into key–value pairs, where keys are the values from "heading1" like so:

```
var data = [
    {heading1:"value1_1",heading2:"value2_1",heading3:"value3_1",heading4:"value4_1",heading5:"value5_1"},
    {heading1:"value1_2",heading2:"value2_2",heading3:"value3_2",heading4:"value4_2",heading5:"value5_2" },
];

var filtered = {};
for (var i = 0, max = data.length; i < max; i++) {
    var record = data[i];

    if (!filtered[record.heading1]) {
        filtered[record.heading1] = {};
    }

    filtered[record.heading1] = record;
}

var keys = Object.keys(filtered);
for (var i = 0, max = keys.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(filtered[keys[i]]); // do print
}
```